# Outlook consolidate files

Tags: excel, vba, outlook, office-automation

I have the following macro to extract and combine excel files from outlook.
The macro does not work on the start with variables declaration.
I get an error:

```
"Compile error
User-defined type not defined"
```

```
Dim OutlookNamespace As Namespace
Dim Folder As MAPIFolder
Dim OutlookMail As Variant
Dim i As Integer
```

Answer (score 0):

It seems you need to add a COM reference in your VBA environment. Use the `Reference` command on the Visual Basic for Applications (VBA) `Tools` menu to set a reference to `Microsoft Outlook xx.x Object Library`, where xx.x represents the version of Outlook that you are working with. See [Automating Outlook from a Visual Basic Application](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/outlook/concepts/getting-started/automating-outlook-from-a-visual-basic-application) for more information.

Also you may need to prepend the type declarations with a host name (namespace):

```
Dim OutlookNamespace As Outlook.Namespace
Dim Folder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
```